# Using software/service to schedule photo shoots

Tags: business

Just wonder if anyone uses any sort of online software or service to schedule your photoshoots.  Such that clients (and prospective clients) can see which dates & times are currently available for portraits.   I find that many times, clients will say "whats your availability in October" and I'll tell a few clients my availability, and it takes them a a few days or weeks to coordinate their schedule, and several clients will write back wanting a date that just got reserved by another customer... and I have to email them my latest times available and the cycle continues.  I feel like I could improve on this process.

I wondered if it would be better customer service to have my available schedule always updated and visible to clients.  I have thought about just a page off my website manually listing currently available dates and times, but wondered if anyone did this through a special software or service that might allow clients to browse through available session date/times ... and even better (but not a requirement): be able to reserve a session time right then and there?  Thanks!

Comment: While you did use the word *photoshoot* so you're on-topic here, this is a highly general problem and there are [solutions available](https://www.google.com/?q=schedule+booking+software). At the very least you can add a Google Calendar widget to a webpage. One of my clients used [Supersaas](http://www.supersaas.com/) which has a free version too.

Comment: Disagree with Itai above. Lots of solutions exist specifically for photographers.

Comment: What @Itai said ... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure lots of people use software to do this. Just using Google Apps or a calendar really sells your business short. What you are talking about is really tracking leads. This can be done with most studio scheduling software. Many of them even have mobile apps so you can book sessions on the go.

Take a look at:

- [Pixifi](http://www.pixifi.com/)
- [ShootQ](http://web.shootq.com/)
- [Studio Cloud](http://studiocloud.com/)
- [Táve](http://www.tave.com/)
- [Yooies](http://yooies.com) - Unreleased, unproven, etc.

As with any software, look for a free trial before jumping in completely.

Answer (score 0):

Check appointy.com too. I have many of my client using it and their free version has no limitations on the number of bookings. They also integrate with Facebook and Twitter to help you promote your business.

Try it and send me my 1 cent for the tip. :)

Answer (score 0):

Many people suffer at the quick sale, and this is where Business School really helps. An MBA is a bit overkill for your question, but it just highlights the problem we all have; we just wanna shoot.

You should find a way to make the quick sale, including entering in the appointment for them, then rescheduling as necessary by calling to confirm. I personally use Exchange calendaring, which works in conjunction with iCal on OSX and Google Calendars, so customers will get their own notifications.